# Running a job while the user is present Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs, broadcast, schedule

I have a laravel app, where users can set up "price watchers" for different assets.
I am getting the current prices via API in a scheduled artisan command (lets say every minute) and broadcasting the price changes to all the users via seperate private channels.
The problem is that the command keeps running even if there are no users on site.
I dont want to spam the API with requests and broadcasting events while there is no present user to see it.

Whats the best approach for this?
Should i dispatch a job manually when someone logs in? But how can i make the job keep running as long as the user is there, and how i can end it after?
Honestly it confuses me pretty much, am i missing something?

Hope my problem is understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could try running a function every time someone logs in which checks whether the job is active or not. If it's not active you can trigger it.

Everytime someone logs out, you can check how many active sessions/ logged in users exist, if this equates to 0 - kill the job

Not sure this is the most elegant solution but in principle should work

**Update**

Actually come to think of it, an even cleaner way of doing all of this would be to use the laravel scheduler. Schedule a job to run every minute, and every single time it runs, you will check if there are any active sessions, if not you just ignore, if active sessions exist, then run your logic

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#defining-schedules

Comment: Hm, checking the active sessions is a good idea, that could work. Thank you!

Any idea how to create a looping job that runs until its killed properly? 
Maybe the 
 
while(true) {
     //...
     sleep(10)
}
could work, but i dont know, it seems something that will crash the server someday or so.
Maybe with some additional workarounds, like restarting the job every X minutes to release memory or something like that. Dunno. It feels pretty dirty. I wander if there is a best practice solution for this.

Thank you for your help anyway, your idea already helped alot!

Comment: @hatja i updated the solution above, i think using the scheduler is the way to go, it should be cleaner this way and you can decouple it from login / logout events per se

Comment: Yeah, that sounds much better. Nice!

As i just checked for this i need to change the session driver to database so the active sessions can be easily queried from the db. 
Also found a  simple package for this too, its pretty old, but the logic can be copied from there for more complex queries. I dont think i'll need this for now, but can be useful for anyone else:
https://github.com/joshrainwater/active-users